# Open sidebar in Google App Script with parent menu

Tags: exception, google-apps-script, google-slides

I am trying to open sidebar in Google App Script with parent menu but without sub-menu.
but error coming **Exception: Cannot call SlidesApp.getUi() from this context.**

**init.gs**

```
function onOpen() {

  showSidebar();

  SlidesApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Test Menu')
      .addItem('Add In', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SlidesApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that if your script is run with the standalone script and the container-bound script except for Google Spreadsheet, such error occurs. So, can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpOI3.png @Tanaike . Please let me what more you required to examine.

Comment: `showSidebar` is a method that requires authorization. Simple triggers are forbidden to call such methods - hence the error. 90% of the time `onOpen` is only useful for creating menus due to the restriction. What you want to do is impossible to achieve - there must be at least one top level menu item.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve this my requirement ? @OlegValter

Comment: @RoshanJha nope, none as far as I know..

Comment: @OlegValter also its not possible with any trigger ? as i read some where , we can call trigger with menu on click , also i read one the Tanike ans with trigger, but i lost the reference :(

Answer (score 0):

### You should change createHtmlOutputFromFile method or create a sidebar.html

This is working correctly if you change the method. By using your code there should be 2 files.

**code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  SlidesApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Test Menu')
      .addItem('Add In', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SlidesApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, world! <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Otherwise you can directly define the HTML using the [createHtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createhtmloutputhtml) method.

**code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  SlidesApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Test Menu')
      .addItem('Add In', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Hello, world! <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SlidesApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

**PoC**

[image]

Comment: Thankyou but i am sure you are not reading my que and my expected result.

Comment: Can you please provide a more in detail description about your expected result? Correct me if I'm wrong, do you want to open the sidebar before the UI is loaded? Because that's the reason why you can't  automatically open the sidebar, the UI class needs context.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpOI3.png here is the screen shot what is issue and what is required result.

Comment: I apologize for my poor understanding about your post but I was talking about `showSidebar();` at the very beginning of your code.